# Websocket server handshake response

Tags: c++, encryption, websocket

I am trying to set up websocket communication. I can open the websocket, but I can't figure out how to get the handshake response correct. According to several sites:

> "Additionally, the server can decide on extension/subprotocol requests here; see Miscellaneous for details. The Sec-WebSocket-Accept part is interesting. The server must derive it from the Sec-WebSocket-Key that the client sent. To get it, concatenate the client's Sec-WebSocket-Key and "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" together (it's a "magic string"), take the SHA-1 hash of the result, and return the base64 encoding of the hash...So if the Key was "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==", the Accept will be "s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers

But I cannot seem to reproduce these results at all. I've tried many encoders/decoders, and tried to find alternate interpretations of the instructions above, but none of them work. I also have not found any examples of code doing this.

Input: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==

Magic string(never changes):258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11

Output: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=

The only way I have ever gotten the correct answer is through [this site](https://hash.online-convert.com/sha1-generator). It seems to get the SHA1 encoding wrong but the overall 64 bit answer is correct? Anyway, help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can always [look at what others did](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/42b71819a0fb6a00c6af126eacc17863cde56460/lib/facil/http/http1.c#L320-L368). It can help you figure out the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
sec_websocket_key = "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ=="
magic_string = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
return base64(sha1(sec_websocket_key .. magic_string))
```

Here's a real implementation that'll work in a UNIX shell, assuming you have OpenSSL installed:

```
SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY="dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ=="
MAGIC_STRING="258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
echo -n "$SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY$MAGIC_STRING" \
    | openssl sha1 -binary \
    | openssl base64
```

Make sure that you're using SHA1 -- not SHA256 -- and that the implementation you're using returns raw data, not a hex digest. The output of the hash function should be 160 bits (20 bytes) long.

Also, keep in mind that, even though `Sec-WebSocket-Key` looks like Base64 data, **you don't need to decode it**. It's included in the hash as-is.